# I am trying to retrieve data from a single key in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from a single key in firebase.

```
var ratingRef = firebase.database().ref("hollywood/");
ratingRef.orderByValue().on("value", function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(data) {
        var name = ("The " + data.val().name + " rating is " + data.val().director + data.val().year);
        var pic = data.val().src;
        alert(pic)
        var fame = $("#tame").attr("src", pic + "<div>")
        $("#test").append(name + " <br>");
    });
});
```

Comment: I made your post a bit m ore readable, but it's still missing a lot of information. I recommend reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Editing your question to align with the guidance in those will give you the best chance that someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it out this way:

```
var ratingRef = firebase.database().ref("hollywood/").orderBy("value");
function checkrating(ratingRef){
  ratingRef.forEach(data => {
    var name = ("The " + data.val().name + " rating is " + data.val().director + data.val().year);
        var pic = data.val().src;
        alert(pic)
        var fame = $("#tame").attr("src", pic + "<div>")
        $("#test").append(name + " <br>");
  });
}
checkrating(ratingRef)
```

if this doesn't help, try explaining the problem further or telling us the error in your console